# Fixed background like Twitter?

Tags: css, twitter, background-image, fixed

On every Twitter profile page there is fixed background image. How could I do the same on my site?

I would like to find a solution in CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use background-attachment for your image

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

try it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment)

Comment: The link to the try it editor makes you first among the equals for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-attachment: fixed;` in CSS. Example CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url('bg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Did you just answer your own question, 2 minutes after asking?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt It is allowed. Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions on meta...

Comment: I know, but why bother asking a question if you're going to post the answer after 2 minutes? ;-)

Comment: ;) Well interesting question, but I think it is OK because StackOverflow is a knowladge base. [As Jeff Atwood repeatedly states in the podcasts: "this site is about building a knowledge base."] So to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

This http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

background-attachment: fixed should to the trick.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-attachment